# What are the taxi options in Aruba?

Tags: taxis, aruba

I'm headed to Aruba soon - what are the taxi options there? Are taxis reliable or should I rent a car?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've stayed in Aruba for a week in February 2023 and this is my experience.

#### Cab pricing and payment

All taxi drivers must follow the [official taxi price list](https://aruba.bynder.com/m/168d9a9a49f92e21/original/Aruba-Official-Taxi-Price-list-2018-2022.pdf) and in my experience all of them did follow it without question. There's no expectation of tipping. All payments are in cash (both USD and florins are accepted), not a single cab I've seen took credit cards.

#### Ordering a taxi by phone

In my experience the most reliable option was [Aruba Taxi Company](https://arubataxicompany.com/), reachable at +(297) 587-1300. Two other operators I've tried either had unreasonable wait times or weren't able to supply a cab in the early hours of the morning. Disclaimer: I have no association with this taxi company other than being a customer.

Based on my experience a cab always showed up within 10 minutes of calling the number above.

#### Hailing a cab on the street

If you're on the main highway or in the hotel zone, you can hail a cab within a couple of minutes of waiting. Anywhere else you might be waiting for a long time as there aren't that many cabs on the island.

#### Apps

There are a few apps in the App Store claiming to allow for "Uber style" ride hailing but none of them seem to work as of 2023.